# A default parent router with child routers

Tags: aurelia

Consider the following two classes:

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class MainPage
{
    router: Router;

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router)
    {
        config.map([
            { route: ['', 'entities'], name: 'entities', moduleId: './entities/entities', nav: true, title: 'Entities' },
            { route: 'structures', name: 'structures', moduleId: './structures/structures', nav: true, title: 'Data Structures' },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

And

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class Entities
{
    private router: Router;

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router)
    {
        config.map([
            { route: '', name: 'entities-list', moduleId: './list', nav: true, title: 'Entities' },
            { route: 'events', name: 'entity-events', moduleId: './events', nav: true, title: 'Events' },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

The problem is that; in a page where the URL reads: `http://localhost/` when I execute:

```
this.router.navigateToRoute('entity-events');
```

I get the error `ERROR [app-router] Error: Route not found: events`. But if I change the `MainPage` class to this:

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class MainPage
{
    router: Router;

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router)
    {
        config.map([
            { route: 'entities', name: 'entities', moduleId: './entities/entities', nav: true, title: 'Entities' },
            { route: 'structures', name: 'structures', moduleId: './structures/structures', nav: true, title: 'Data Structures' },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

In a page that URL reads `http://localhost/entities`, I can successfully execute the given `navigateToRoute` command. But then I'll lose the root route!

So how can I have a parent router with a default route and some child routes under the default route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a redirect route to redirect the default route to `entities`? I'm on mobile right no, so no code sample, but the docs should explain it.