# Why I'm not getting the params in activate method?

Tags: aurelia

Working more on [my previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208744/a-default-parent-router-with-child-routers), I've got three classes. First the parent:

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class MainPage
{
    router: Router;

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router)
    {
        config.map([
            { route: '', redirect: 'entities' },
            { route: 'entities', name: 'entities', moduleId: './entities/entities', nav: true, title: 'Entities' },
            { route: 'structures', name: 'structures', moduleId: './structures/structures', nav: true, title: 'Data Structures' },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

Then the bigger brother:

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class Entities
{
    private router: Router;

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router)
    {
        config.map([
            { route: '', name: 'entities-list', moduleId: './list', nav: true, title: 'Entities' },
            { route: ':name/events', name: 'entity-events', moduleId: './events', nav: true, title: 'Events' },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

And finally the little sister:

```
import { inject, computedFrom } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Services } from './services';

@inject(Services)
export class Event
{
    private events = [];

    constructor(private services : Services) {}

    async attached(params, routeConfig)
    {
        debugger;
        this.events = <any> await this.services.getEvents(params.name);
    }
}
```

And I use the following method call to navigate to the little sister:

```
this.router.navigateToRoute('entity-events', { name: "Some Name" });
```

But when I get to the `debugger` breakpoint, there's no `params`, it's `undefined`. According to the documentation, there supposed to be an object passed to the `activate` method, containing the parameters of the route. Where did go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use the `activate` method.

The params argument is passed to `activate`, not `attached` as you've written above.

```
async activate(params, routeConfig)
{
    debugger;
    this.events = <any> await this.services.getEvents(params.name);
}
```

Comment: although you mention `activate` in the question, so I imagine this is not a real question and just a typo

Comment: It seems like I've been too tired last night!

Comment: I stumbled across this trying to work out why my `activate` (yes, really, `activate`) did not work :). Turns out that it does work if I drop `async` but the example here uses `async` is `async` supported with params?